# Question relating to storage of radioactive substances

Tags: radioactivity

I saw this para while reading my physics textbook which said that radioactive substances were kept in thick lead containers with a very narrow opening. I understood the purpose of the lead but what is the purpose of the opening? Won't this lead to leakage of radiations?[image]

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Please consider writing descriptive question titles with appropriate punctuation, grammar, and formatting. See this meta post: [How do we write good question titles?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6413).

Comment: One presumably needs an opening to get the material out. But I agree that it is horribly worded...

Comment: @JonCuster  so the function of the opening is just to retrieve the contents of the container, right?

Comment: That is about all I can figure. As I say, the passage is worded quite badly. Alpha particles can be kept in tissue paper (it even says thin metal sheet, yet the passage above insists on thick lead - just weird).

Comment: @JonCuster k thks 

Comment: That doesn't sound like a storage container: It sounds like a _[collimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimator)_.  The opening is,... um,... _open_, and because it is narrow and deep, the radiation that escapes through it is confined to a narrow cone.

Comment: ...Of course, the same vessel can serve two purposes. If you put a plug in the opening, it becomes a storage container. When you remove the plug, it becomes a collimator. You can move it around, and you can turn it "on" (i.e., remove the plug), and you can turn it "off" (replace the plug) without ever handling the source.

Comment: Thks Solomon for the help appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think it *probably* isn't saying that the container *must be open* (albeit *narrowly*), but rather that such opening as it obviously *must* have for accessing the contents ought to be narrow. Radiation particles travel in straight lines, without even any significant diffraction at edges (the wavelength of γ-radiation is *extremely* small even in comparison to the *sharpest possible* edge in a macroscopic substance); and having a narrow opening minimises the chance of the contents lying in a line-of-sight to whomever is opening it.